# How to make a labview loop stall once?

Tags: loops, labview

I am kinda new to LabView and the problem is the following: I want to stall just when values are different and not stalling after the update. The **wrong** way would be:

wrong way: new value different from old
[image]

wrong way: new value equals old
[image]

I highlighted it is the wrong way because the loop still stalls even in case false, that does not contain a stall structure.

Edit: link to code: [download here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13PUEYIMQxplyw7Gfu-wAlyMN8WoQ7J-C)

Comment: Please, show your complete VI - because it is difficult to tell what is wrong just based on this small snippet.

Comment: thanks for reading this @kosist, this is the whole VI I'm using, it will be used as part in other VIs.

Comment: Hi @Paulo, consider reviewing the given answers and either accept one as the answer or provide more information, so that this topic can be closed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Testing:

I implemented the code in my LabVIEW and it seems to work just fine! If the values b_in and b_out are different, it waits the preset time, if they are the same, it doesn't wait. You could use the **"Highlight Execution"** button to test it in your code.

### Solution:

If you let it run in a loop, maybe there is a **race condition**. Local variables are predestined for that problem. I would use them as rarely as possible. If you run the case-structure in a loop, you should use **`shift-registers`** instead.

There are some unclear points in the question, that can't be answered without further information, so please provide an edit for these:

- Is this just a part of a bigger vi?
- Can you provide the code of the whole vi?
- Does the code snippet of your question run in a loop?

(I will edit the answer if new information is provided)

Hope, I could help you :)

Comment: Actually, there is no such term as dataflow collision, but instead better to use race condition. But overall you are right, as local variables - are pure evil in LabVIEW.

Comment: *Local variables are pure evil in LabVIEW* needs to be qualified. They are often the right tool to use for updating a UI indicator from different places in a diagram at different times - for example, from different frames of a case structure or state machine - or for reading a control from different places in a diagram, like two asynchronous loops.

Comment: Dear @nekomatic - all the use cases which you've described are possible to implement without usage of local variables, it's a matter of the architecture. Ask any CLA guy, and they will tell you whole lecture why not to use local variables, and the ways how you can substitute them with something better.

Comment: @Salome, thanks for reading my question, the answers for your questions are:


* **Is this just a part of a bigger VI?** I'm testing this part before adding it to other VIs.

* **Can you provide the code of the whole vi?** Just did

* **Does the code snippet of your question run in a loop?** I use the "Execute in a loop" option, not in a loop structure.

Comment: Hi, no Problem :) Thanks for the answers. Please edit them in your question too, so others can find this information without looking through the comments. Some more questions: I see that you use a **wait**-control, probably for the time that should be waited. **- Which value do you use?** The Stall Data Flow VI uses milliseconds as input and as output. Maybe the time-value you use is too low to it while the code is running.

Comment: **- Did you try the Highlight Execution function?** As far as I understand the question, the vi does what you want. If not, please clearify what it should do :)

Answer (score 2):

As Salome pointed out, I have recreated your requirement with Feedback nodes.

[image: Using Feedback Nodes]

Let me know if you need any more assistance with it!

Answer (score 2):

In Labview 2018 you could also use the "Is Value Changed" function.
The SubVI is just syntax suger, which is realized by the polymorphism of malleable VIs. The functionality is the same as Salome suggests.

[image: Is Value Changed]